# Custom URL scheme for an iOS app with dropbox oauth2 authorization?

Tags: ios, qt, oauth-2.0, redirect, dropbox-api

I'm trying to utilize dropbox with my Qt-based iOS app. My problem is the redirection from the dropbox authorization webpage back to the app. 
I did not manage to get the dropbox authorization to work with the Qt WebView, so I am simply launching the default browser to the dropbox authorization site.

According to the dropbox dev portal, for the redirect_uri parameter, you can only use the https scheme for external addresses, and the http scheme for localhost addresses.

Does this make it impossible for the redirection to utilize a URL scheme that I have configured for my app, such as: 'myapp://' ?

How should I have dropbox redirecting back to my app? Should I use a custom website that redirects to my app using the URL scheme, or should I have my app as a server that listens to some port on localhost, so that I would use 'http://localhost:[port number]'? Suggestions? Are these even possible?

Can a URL scheme be used somehow in connection with a 'http://localhost' -based URL?

It is of course possible to omit the redirect_uri and let the user to copy the authorization code or token, switch back to my app, and paste it to a text field, but I think this would be a bit of a hassle to the user.

Answer (score 3):

One important thing to note here is that the Dropbox API OAuth 2 implementation offers two different flows, "code" and "token". The code flow does require https://, unless it's a localhost URL, in which case it allows http:// or https:// (only).

You can use other protocols with the token flow though. Here are the variations broken out, with the result/error for each.

**With `redirect_uri`:**

*code flow:*

- https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize?client_id=APP_KEY&response_type=code&redirect_uri=myapp://dropbox_callback

  - "Invalid redirect_uri: "myapp://dropbox_callback": When response_type=code, redirect_uri must start with "https://", unless it's a localhost URI."
- https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize?client_id=APP_KEY&response_type=code&redirect_uri=myapp://localhost/dropbox_callback

  - "Invalid redirect_uri: "myapp://localhost/dropbox_callback": When response_type=code, localhost URIs may only start with "http://" or "https://"."

*token flow:*

- https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize?client_id=APP_KEY&response_type=token&redirect_uri=myapp://dropbox_callback

  - 200 (this is the version that probably makes the most sense for you to use)

**Without `redirect_uri`:**

*code flow:*

- https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize?client_id=APP_KEY&response_type=code

  - 200

*token flow:*

- https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize?client_id=APP_KEY&response_type=token

  - "Missing redirect_uri (required when "response_type" is "token")"

Comment: Thanks for your input. I should add that I was not able to add the URL scheme address to the list of recirect_uris in the dropbox app dashboard. Currently I am simply using a custom website to redirect to my app. My current problem is catching the params. A question: In your example app scheme URL (myapp://dropbox_callback), what does the string 'dropbox_callback' denote? Is it some 'virtual' folder/directory for the app or etc? A function name? Currently I only understand how to invoke my app by a simple URL scheme address that only has the scheme part of the URL, such as: 'myapp://'.

Comment: The "dropbox_callback" portion was arbitrary and made-up.

Comment: Also, what do you mean you couldn't add the URL scheme address? If you ran in to an issue with the site, please feel free to open a ticket: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/contact

Comment: But does that portion have any significance in the event when the app is evoked? Would it be handled as a parameter in the network event? -- Sorry, I'm not yet 100% familiar with URL scheming, and launching apps this way. If anyone could chime in, I would appreciate it.

Comment: By not being able to add the URL scheme address I mean that in the dropbox dev console for my app there is the list of redirect_uris. If I try to add, for example 'myapp://', I get the red error message on top of the text field: 'You must provide a proper URI with an authority or path component'. And this is despite having 'Allow implicit grant' set to 'Allow', which I would presume means allowing the token flow. However, I do am trying to do things using the code flow, which is more secure.

Comment: I believe the app can check that portion when that URL is invoked, launching the app, so you can choose whatever you want and check it in the app. (E.g., in case you have multiple such events to catch.)

Comment: Regarding that error, you'll need to register something like "myapp://dropbox_callback", and not just "myapp://".

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. So it seems that this portion does have a great significance here after all. Would you happen to know if these "addresses" are something that is configurable in the info.plist, or if their usage convention details depend on the framework that you are using? -- Anyways, I'll be checking into how to catch the parameters and perhaps this also with Qt. For me, the code flow with external redirecting page is ok for now.

Comment: They're significant in that way, but you can pick and configure whatever you want.

Comment: So you can configure them? -- Succeeded to catch the redirect call URL in Qt with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28822086/best-way-to-get-source-url-of-custom-ios-scheme-in-qml

Comment: Small note: To be able to register `myapp://...` instead of `https://...` can be important, if the OS needs a registered intent (e.g. Android). With a `https` redirect uri the OS will launch the choose browser dialog, while a custom scheme like `myapp` can be intercepted silently. Spent quite some time figuring this out.